# Magento2 Add custom field to review form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, review, product-review

I am trying to add a custom field in review form in the product page. Below is my code:

**InstallData.php**

```
namespace Namespace\Mymodule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
Class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
     public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
     {
        $installer = $setup;
        $setup->startSetup();
       // $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $reviewTable = 'review_detail';

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($reviewTable),
            'refer_field',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'label' => 'Would you recommend this product to a friend',
                'comment' =>'Would you recommend this product to a friend',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 101,
                'position' => 101,
                'system' => 0,
                'option' =>
                    array (
                        'values' =>
                            array (
                                0 => 'Yes',
                                1 => 'No',
                            ),
                    ),
                        ]
        );
         $setup->endSetup();
     }
}
```

**app/code/Namespace/Mymodule/view/frontend**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="review_product_form_component"/>
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews_tab" as="reviews" template="Namespace_Mymodule::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="review_form" template="Namespace_Mymodule::form.phtml" as="review_form">
                    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Namespace/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Review\Block\Form
 */
?>
<div class="block review-add">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Write Your Own Review') ?></strong></div>
<div class="block-content">
<?php if ($block->getAllowWriteReviewFlag()): ?>
<form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAction() ?>" class="review-form" method="post" id="review-form" data-role="product-review-form" data-bind="scope: 'review-form'">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset review-fieldset" data-hasrequired="<?php __('* Required Fields'); ?>">
        <legend class="legend review-legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("You're reviewing:"); ?></span><strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductInfo()->getName()) ?></strong></legend><br />
        <?php if ($block->getRatings() && $block->getRatings()->getSize()): ?>
        <span id="input-message-box"></span>
        <fieldset class="field required review-field-ratings">
            <legend class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Your Rating') ?><span></legend><br/>
            <div class="control">
                <div class="nested" id="product-review-table">
                    <?php foreach ($block->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                        <div class="field choice review-field-rating">
                            <label class="label" id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control review-control-vote">
                            <?php $options = $_rating->getOptions();?>
                            <?php $iterator = 1; foreach ($options as $_option): ?>
                                <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="ratings[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_rating->getId() ?>]"
                                    id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>"
                                    value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getId() ?>"
                                    class="radio"
                                    data-validate="{required:true, messages:{required:'Please select one of each of the ratings above.'}}"
                                    aria-labelledby="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>_label" />
                                <label
                                    class="rating-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $iterator; ?>"
                                    for="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>"
                                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? 'stars' : 'star') ?>"
                                    id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>_label">
                                    <span><?php /*@escapeNotVerified*/ echo __('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? 'stars' : 'star') ?></span>
                                </label>
                            <?php $iterator++; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="validate_rating" class="validate-rating" value="" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <?php endif ?>
        <div class="field review-field-nickname required">
            <label for="nickname_field" class="label"><span><?php /*@escapeNotVerified*/ echo __('Nickname') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: nickname()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field review-field-summary required">
            <label for="summary_field" class="label"><span><?php /*@escapeNotVerified*/ echo __('Summary') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: review().title" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field review-field-text required">
            <label for="review_field" class="label"><span><?php /*@escapeNotVerified*/ echo __('Review') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="detail" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: review().detail"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field review-field-refer required">
          <label for="review_field" class="label"><span><?php/*@escapeNotVerified*/ echo __('Would you recommend this product to a friend') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
               <select name="refer_field">
               <option name="yes" value="yes">Yes</option>
               <option name="no" value="no">No</option>
               </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar review-form-actions">
        <div class="primary actions-primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span><?php/*@escapeNotVerified*/ echo __('Submit Review') ?></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=product-review-form]": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
    },
    "#review-form": {
        "Magento_Review/js/error-placement": {}
    }
}
</script>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info notlogged" id="review-form">
        <div>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href="%1">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2">create an account</a>', $block->getLoginLink(), $block->getRegisterUrl()) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
</div>
```

What is the proper way to save data in the database and how to show the same field in the admin panel where review form appears?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean review appear in front-end  right?

Comment: that custom field should show in frontend and backend form  and saved in database.

Comment: What template you are using..?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. I have created two custom fields in the registration form (by overriding the 'register.phtml')..I want to save their values in the database (attribute IDs have been successfully created in the DB through InstallData.php)..Please let me know if you have found any solution to this..

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the ResourceModel. At 4 am in morning I am able to figure it now :-)

Add the below XML:

```
<preference for="Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review" type="NS\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Review" />
```

and add the following php code:

```
<?php

namespace NS\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

/**
 * Review resource model
 */
class Review extends \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review
{
    /**
     * Perform actions after object save
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _afterSave(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        /**
         * save detail
         */
        $detail = [
            'title' => $object->getTitle(),
            'detail' => $object->getDetail(),
            'nickname' => $object->getNickname(),
            'refer_field' => $object->getReferField(),
        ];
.
.
.
```

Just overwrite the function "_afterSave" not the whole file.

Comment: Is there any way to do it by plugin. I am trying hard but not able to find.

Comment: As you know only public methods behaviour can be changed by plugins, it might not be possible

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you add new column to table so you should create file **InstallSchema.php**, not **InstallData.php** in your description.

And some code is unused, I think the code below is enough.

```
namespace Namespace\Mymodule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
Class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
     public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
     {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $reviewTable = 'review_detail';

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($reviewTable),
                'refer_field',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' =>'Would you recommend this product to a friend'
                ]
        );
         $setup->endSetup();
     }
}
```